# SAS Entreprise Guide 8.2 - Export Table as CSV to FTP server

Tags: sas, ftp, export, export-to-csv

In SAS entreprise Guide I want to export a table as a CSV file to a FTP server.
I'm saving the table as a csv on my SAS server and then want to export it.

I'm defining the FTP connection and want to write my file in the 'SAS' folder on this FTP

```
filename myftp ftp host='hostname' cd='/SAS/' 
    user='username' pass='password' 
    debug;
```

Afterwards I'm exporting my table to a csv file on my sas server and assigning a filename to this csv file

```
proc export data=WORK.TABLE_DATA
   outfile="/sas/prd/data/output/Test.csv"
   dbms=csv
   replace;
run;

filename csv_file "/sas/prd/data/output/Test.csv";
```

Then I'm exporting this csv to the server

```
proc export
   file=myftp outfile=csv_file
   dbms=csv replace;
run;
```

Script runs succesful but no file appears when I'm checking in the FTP.
Is there any mistake in how I define the FTP reference? Or in the export step? Or both?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Copying a file to an SFTP server is not an "export".  It is just a copy.  Can you write anything to the SFTP server using the MYFTP fileref you define.  Does this program run and create a simple one line file?  `data _null_; file myftp; put 'hello'; run;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom mentioned in his comment, `PROC EXPORT` only exports SAS datasets to other formats. In addition, the filename statement for ftp is missing some elements, here's an example where we're writing a file called 'Test.csv' in the '/SAS/' directory, with numbers 1 to 10:

```
filename create ftp 'Test.csv' cd='/SAS/'
   host='hostname'
   user='user' password="password";
data _null_;
   file create;
   do i=1 to 10;
      put i=;
   end;
run;
```

You may be able to try using `PROC EXPORT` with the fileref from the `filename ftp` statement, however I don't have a SAS installation or FTP server handy for testing:

```
filename create ftp 'Test.csv' cd='/SAS/'
   host='hostname'
   user='user' password="password";

proc export data=WORK.TABLE_DATA
   outfile=create
   dbms=csv
   replace;
run;
```